# Hashicorp is now sponsoring DevOps: Sorry there wasn't a head's up

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship, announcement

*Why don't processes ever go on a road trip?
Because they're afraid of breaking down!*

Thank you for that joke Spencer G. Philippe’s influence is rubbing off. Anyway, that is why I am here: cause one of our processes indeed broke down. I am addressing an issue that some of you have probably noticed already: we landed a sweet sponsorship for DevOps from Hashicorp, but we screwed up and failed to give the prior heads-up that we promised.

We could blame the coffee machine for brewing decaf instead of espresso, or the office dog was too cute to focus on work. But let's be honest; we don't need scapegoats or fluffy distractions. In reality, it was a simple mix-up, a human error, or, as Spencer would say, "a momentary lapse in communication brilliance."

We do have a process internally between teams to inform us when sponsorships are confirmed and a message was lost between stakeholders. There were some recent shifting of teams involved in this process, and no matter how iron clad you think processes are, things will slip through the cracks.

We genuinely apologize for any confusion or inconvenience this may have caused. We are currently looking for the holes that this process fell into so that we can patch them up and restore order for future processes.

### What you need to know about this sponsorship

Hashicorp will be running their sponsorship from now until **December 29, 2023**.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship can be found on the right side of the header at the top of the site, just as it looks now.

### What else changes?

Not a thing! Borrowing from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

### What if I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's all. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making DevOps successful.

If you have any questions or concerns, please let me know.

*PS We don’t have an office dog; we are a remote company, so we have many dogs, cats, and other furry/feathery/scaly friends. I do have a bunny. Hopefully, she’ll serve as a distraction and I share her as part of our apology. Cleo (the bunny) is sorry too.*

[image: Brown lop ear rabbit]

Comment: Meta isn't _just_ for questions (as in things that end with a "?" as you said), since it is also the place for announcements — which is what this is, @Pierre.Vriens ^_^

Comment: I think the problem here is that devops.se is a little too chill for Spencer G. Phillipe references and bunnies.  Cute bunny though!

Comment: The company name is "Hashicorp", rather than "Hashicorps", so you may wish to edit accordingly.

Comment: @SteveStorck I took the liberty to edit it.